# Why is the Scrollbar not working?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scrollbar

## THis is my code for TKinter GUI:

```
from tkinter import *;
from tkinter import ttk
# import tix as tk

class pryprotclass:

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event,canvas1):
       canvas1.configure(scrollregion=canvas1.bbox("all"))

    def __init__(self,master):

       frame2=Frame(master);
       frame2.configure(background='yellow')
       frame2.pack_propagate(False) ;
       frame2.pack(fill="both", expand=True,side=RIGHT);
       canvas1 = Canvas(frame2, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
       canvas1.configure(scrollregion=canvas1.bbox("all"))
       frame3=Frame(canvas1);

       vsb = Scrollbar(frame3, orient="vertical", command=canvas1.yview)
       canvas1.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
       vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
       canvas1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
       canvas1.create_window((4,4), window=frame3, anchor="nw")
       canvas1.configure(scrollregion=canvas1.bbox("all"))
       frame3.bind("<Configure>"), 
       canvas1.configure(scrollregion=canvas1.bbox("all"))
       frame3.config( width=240 );
       frame3.configure(background='purple')
       frame3.pack_propagate(False) ;
```

now there are around 40 labels now to they take up the entire y direction

See image--https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEfxC.jpg

What is the error in the code?

Neither is the scrollbar working nor am I able to see the bar in the scrollbar to move up or down?

here is the requested code (unneccessary)

```
    label=Label(frame3,text='ALL TASKS')
    label.configure(background="WHITE",font="Courier 14 bold")
    label.pack(side=TOP,anchor="nw",padx=10,pady=10)

    chromelogo=PhotoImage(file="./Images/chrome.gif")
    chromelogo=chromelogo.subsample(16,16)
    labelchrome=Label(frame3,text="Chrome")
    labelchrome.config(image=chromelogo)
    labelchrome.config(background='WHITE')
    labelchrome.config(compound='left')
    labelchrome.image=chromelogo
    labelchrome.pack(side=TOP,anchor="nw")
    c1=Checkbutton(frame3,text="History")
    c2=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Cookies")
    c3=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Saved Passwords")
    c4=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Download History")
    c5=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Last Download Location")
    c1.config(background='WHITE')
    c2.config(background='WHITE')
    c3.config(background='WHITE')
    c4.config(background='WHITE')
    c5.config(background='WHITE')
    c1.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c2.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c3.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c4.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c5.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)


    firefoxlogo=PhotoImage(file="./Images/firefox.gif")

    firefoxlogo=firefoxlogo.subsample(18,18)
    labelfirefox=Label(frame3,text="Firefox")
    labelfirefox.config(background='WHITE')

    labelfirefox.config(image=firefoxlogo)
    labelfirefox.config(compound='left')
    labelfirefox.image=firefoxlogo
    labelfirefox.pack(side=TOP,anchor="nw")
    c6=Checkbutton(frame3,text="History")
    c7=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Cookies")
    c8=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Saved Passwords")
    c9=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Internet Cache")
    c10=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Saved Form Information")
    c6.config(background='WHITE')
    c7.config(background='WHITE')
    c8.config(background='WHITE')
    c9.config(background='WHITE')
    c10.config(background='WHITE')
    c6.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c7.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c8.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c9.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c10.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)


    iexplorelogo=PhotoImage(file="./Images/iexplore.gif")

    iexplorelogo=iexplorelogo.subsample(12,12)
    labeliexplore=Label(frame3,text="Internet Explorer")
    labeliexplore.config(image=iexplorelogo)
    labeliexplore.config(background='WHITE')

    labeliexplore.config(compound='left')
    labeliexplore.image=iexplorelogo
    labeliexplore.pack(side=TOP,anchor="nw")
    c11=Checkbutton(frame3,text="History")
    c12=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Cookies")
    c13=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Last Download Location")
    c14=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Temporary Internet Files")
    c15=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Autocomplete Form History")
    c11.config(background='WHITE')
    c12.config(background='WHITE')
    c13.config(background='WHITE')
    c14.config(background='WHITE')
    c15.config(background='WHITE')
    c11.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c12.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c13.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c14.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c15.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    explorerlogo=PhotoImage(file="./Images/explorer.gif")
    explorerlogo=explorerlogo.subsample(16,16)
    explorerlabel=Label(frame3,text="Windows Explorer")
    explorerlabel.config(image=explorerlogo)
    explorerlabel.config(background='WHITE')
    explorerlabel.config(compound='left')
    explorerlabel.image=explorerlogo
    explorerlabel.pack(side=TOP,anchor="nw")
    c16=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Recent Documents")
    c17=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Run(in Start Menu)")
    c18=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Network Passwords")
    c16.config(background='WHITE')
    c17.config(background='WHITE')
    c18.config(background='WHITE')
    c16.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c17.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c18.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    systemlogo=PhotoImage(file="./Images/system.gif")

    systemlogo=systemlogo.subsample(16,16)
    systemlabel=Label(frame3,text="System")
    systemlabel.config(image=systemlogo)
    systemlabel.config(background='WHITE')
    systemlabel.config(compound='left')
    systemlabel.image=systemlogo
    systemlabel.pack(side=TOP,anchor="nw")
    c19=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Recycle Bin")
    c20=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Temporary Files")
    c21=Checkbutton(frame3,text="Clipboard")
    c22=Checkbutton(frame3,text="DNS Cache")
    #c23=Checkbutton(frame3,text="add")
    c19.config(background='WHITE')
    c20.config(background='WHITE')
    c21.config(background='WHITE')
    c22.config(background='WHITE')
    c19.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c20.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c21.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    c22.pack(anchor="nw",padx=30)
    frame3.pack(fill="y", expand=False,side="left");
    frame4=Frame(frame2);
    frame4.configure(background='PINK')
    frame4.pack_propagate(False) ;
    frame5=Frame(frame4)
    frame5.configure(background='green')
    progressbar=ttk.Progressbar(frame4,orient=HORIZONTAL)
    progressbar.pack(fill=BOTH,padx=20,pady=15)
    run_PryPro=Button(frame4,text="RUN")

    frame5.configure(height=300)
    frame5.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True,padx=20)
    run_PryPro.pack(padx=60,pady=25,ipadx=20,ipady=10)
    frame4.packfill="both", expand=True,side="right");
```

## main Class's Code as requested ==

```
from tkinter import * ;
from lefttoolbar import *;
from pyprot import *;
from logotop import *;
root=Tk()
obj_pryprot=pryprotclass(root);
=root.minsize(800, 500);

root.mainloop();
```

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46624488/why-is-the-scrollbar-not-working-in-heretkinterpython-3-4

Comment: Why do you think the scrollbar should be working? The canvas only has one item in it, a tiny frame. There's nothing to scroll.

Comment: I haven't added the code for the the things don't you see the picture ? There are many things in it

Comment: It will only make things complex unnecessarily

Comment: To have a proper [mcve], it must illustrate the problem. Not almost look sort-of like the code that illustrates the problem. For the purposes of this question you can add a simple loop that adds a hundred labels to the frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the scrollbar not working in here(Tkinter(Python 3.4))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46624488/why-is-the-scrollbar-not-working-in-heretkinterpython-3-4)

Comment: NOT A DUPLICATE PLEASE SEE

Comment: please don't have hundreds of lines of code. You can add labels with a simple loop. It should take no more than three lines.

Comment: I think you may be confused as the what a MCVE is. Like Bryan said you don't need a hundred lines of code to provide a MCVE. All you need is a simple class with a loop that creates many identical labels to illustrate the problem. Note your code is not executable as is. How are we calling your class `pryprotclass` ?

Comment: obj_pryprot=pryprotclass(root);root.minsize(800, 500);

root.mainloop();

Comment: Don't post that in comments. It needs to be in your question.

Comment: I think I can see why your scrollbar is not working. The widgets at the bottom are shrinking with the window resize. I need to read through your code to see why this is happening.

Comment: There is some good info on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30352571/widgets-become-invisible-when-i-shrink-my-window-tkinter-python) about why the widgets are being removed from viability when the window resizes.

Comment: Edited the Question

Comment: zzz123 Bryan's post is correct. I was about to post a similar answer but there is no need now. In the future please follow Bryan's example as his post shows what a MCVE should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more methodical in writing your code. I count at least nine bugs in your code. You need to start by creating as few widgets as possible, and then add features only when you know the existing features are working correctly. It's very difficult to debug eight things at once.

Here are the things that need fixing:

- [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends that class names begin with an uppercase character
- You need to remove `frame3.pack_propagate(False)`. Turning off geometry propagation is an advanced feature that you almost never should use.
- You need to remove `frame2.pack_propagate(False)`
- You need to make the scrollbar a child of `frame2`, not `frame3`, since `frame3` is what you want to scroll. As a general rules, scrollbars and the things they scroll should have the same parent/master
- You need to give the canvas a size
- you need to make `canvas1` be an instance variable
- Your bind needs to associate a function with the event
- The bound function needs to take a single argument
- The bound function needs to use `self.canvas1` rather than `canvas1`

Here's a version of your code with all of those issues fixed:

```
from tkinter import *;

class Pryprotclass:

    def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
        self.canvas1.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas1.bbox("all"))

    def __init__(self,master):

       frame2=Frame(master);
       frame2.pack(fill="both", expand=True, side=RIGHT);

       self.canvas1 = Canvas(frame2, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
       vsb = Scrollbar(frame2, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas1.yview)
       self.canvas1.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

       self.canvas1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
       vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")

       frame3=Frame(self.canvas1);
       self.canvas1.create_window((4,4), window=frame3, anchor="nw")
       frame3.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure), 

       # dummy widgets for testing
       for i in range(100):
           label = Label(frame3, text="Item #%s" % i)
           label.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=10, pady=1)



root = Tk()
p = Pryprotclass(root)
root.mainloop()
```